# asynch process in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, asynchronous, migration

I am migrating an app written on asp.net 1.1. There is a process which can take 5 minutes on one page, processing data in SQL, and letting the user know when it's complete.

To get around the HTTP page timeout, the process runs asynchronously and the page refreshes every 5 seconds checking for completion. It's very simple. Here is the problem: I use a session variable as a semaphore to signal process completion.

This is not working now as I cannot read the semaphore set in the asynch process. The asynch process can read the session from the calling routine, but cannot write back.

First, is there a way to get the asynch process to write to a session variable which can be read by another process? This probably is not the best approach today, but getting the app working is my biggest priority.

Second, if I rewrite it, what approach should be used? This is an asp web app. Not MVC.

Answer (score 0):

use callback technologie it allow you to query an operation server side from your client and get a return from server so no session to manage any more:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178210(v=vs.80).aspx